# Serious SLComposeViewController issue in iOS 9 with Facebook App installed

Tags: ios, slcomposeviewcontroller

This just came up today because it looks like Apple activated the short links betweens apps.

When creating a SLComposeViewController using SLServiceTypeFacebook and presenting it, right now a new bar appears at the bottom with two options "Write Post" & "Search". If you tap outside the bar the callback is called with the result  SLComposeViewControllerResultDone instead of SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled.

This seems like a new feature and looks like a bug from Apple. I did fill a bug, mainly just raising attention so more people see it

Comment: Well now it seems it doesn't happen anymore...

Comment: I'm definitely still seeing this bug. What made it go away from you? Did you have the Facebook SDK added to your project as well?

Comment: @blkhp19 yes, I have the Facebook 4.5 SDK in the app as well. I didn't do anything to make it go away. Perhaps changing the group to which you send might help